# codeigniter and routes

Tags: codeigniter, custom-routes

yestreday I thought that I had a problem with the ssl in shared ssl but the problem is because of the structure of the url - not because its ssl.

the home page loads ok (besides images but that's ok)
https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/
this is because the defaulr controller is used so CI doesn't have to figure out the uri structure

when there is a class in the url, codeigniter doesn't even show it's own error page.
for example,
https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/aaa
shows 404 error
also without https in the url I get the same error

without the shared ssl structure its working

mode_rewrite is working fine (checked it without CI)

Comment: I checked and found this URL works, https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/index.php/aaa/ so you need to remove index.php from your urls, which can be done by changing a config in config.php

Comment: nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/index.php/aaa does not work. it shows you the homepage instead  of writing test to the page. CI sends you to index.php if it can't figure out the url

Comment: did you make the changes I have mentioned?

Comment: if you go to www.myatar.co.cc you will see that it's working fine (even if you will not understand the language...)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `base_url` in conf file from `http` to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

In your applications/config.php in change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';//mod_rewrite enabled`, moreover in CI, your controller must have `index()` method if you are not using `controller/methodname` but trying to call urls like `controller/` to avoid 404 error.

Comment: $config['index_page'] = '' is indeed empty and it has an index(0 method. it works fine in a normal url structure. I simply can't figure out the problem

Comment: enabled logging and if you could share your configs and class, just the declaration etc, would be helpful